# Logstash date parsing

Tags: logstash, grok

I am having issue mapping my date to @timestamp

Here is the log format ( 0 - 12 for hr - below eg is for 8 PM )

> 09/04/2014 8:14:12

I am filtering it as below -

> %{DATESTAMP:StatshttpDate}

I tried both below and do not seem to work. 
         date {
                 match => [ "StatshttpDate", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss" ]
                 target => "@timestamp"
             }

```
     date {
             match => [ "StatshttpDate", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" ]
             target => "@timestamp"
         }
```

Comment: What do you mean " 0 - 12 for hr - below eg is for 8 PM"?  if the example is PM, so, how the AM hour show?

Comment: The AM and PM really looks same. I guess that is part of the problem. We have to change the logging format I suppose ?

Comment: YES!! You have to change your logs format!